# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, import, modulenotfounderror

im a student
im using vs code for a while. i just started using numpy module first tim e  it worked perfectly later im getting a n error that shows that numpy module not found
i installed the fresh python from python.org as interepeter

i tried changing intrepeter and i tried closing and opening vs code but nothing worked out

Comment: "i installed the fresh python from python.org as interepeter" - that is exactly why it is not found. Numpy **does not come with** Python. It must be installed separately, **for each** Python installation.